# Open a Jupyter Notebook with Python 3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running Python2 on a Jupyter Notebook.

When I try to do:

`import emcee`

I get the error:

```
File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/emcee/ensemble.py", line 84
    parameter_names: Optional[Union[Dict[str, int], List[str]]] = None,
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this because I am using Python2 and should be running Python3?

If I do `python -V` and `python3 -V` in my terminal, I get `Python 2.7.17` and `Python 3.6.9` respectively.

So is there an easy way to open a python 3 Jupyter Notebook? I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

---

When I search for answers, I see solutions that involve installing anaconda - but I already have both Jupyter Notebook and Python 3 on my machine. I don't want to mess things up by installing further versions of python and Jupyter Notebook if I don't need to.

Comment: *Is this because I am using Python2 and should be running Python3?* Yes. Python 2 is reporting a syntax error when it encounters a type hint, which did not exist in Python 2.  You need to install Python 3, which you can do alongside Python 2.

Comment: Thank you. I do seem to have python 3 on my machine. But I don't get a python 3 option when opening a notebook. Do I need to install something further?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply typing in Jupyter notebook directly into your terminal without changing your location within the terminal. It may help to open a fresh terminal session and typing: jupyter notebook.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. I already open my notebook by typing `jupyter notebook` in the terminal. Do you mean from my home directory? That doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Is a jupyter notebook running?